# SPRESENSEのSCUイベント検出機能について

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSE開発ガイド、11.8.5. センサーデータへの信号処理に記載されているSCUのイベント検出機能を使用したプログラムを作りたいと考えております。
SDKにシーケンサFIFOを使用したサンプルがあるのを見つけたのですが、イベント検出を使用したサンプルはございますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

Spresense SDKではBosch Sensortec製のBMI160センサを使用した
`tilt`というサンプルを提供しています。

BMI160についてはこちらが利用可能です。
https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/5258/

SCUイベント検出機能を使って基板の傾きを検出しています。
本サンプルの動作確認方法について簡単にご説明します。

**■コンフィギュレーションファイル作成**

Cloneしたリポジトリにて
`sdk/configs/examples/tilt-defconfig` ファイルを作成して以下の内容を記述します。

```
CONFIG_CXD56_I2C0=y
CONFIG_SENSORS=y
CONFIG_BMI160=y
CONFIG_BMI160_I2C=y
CONFIG_EXAMPLES_TILT=y
```

**■コンフィギュレーションとビルド方法**

```
$ cd sdk
$ ./tools/config.py examples/tilt
$ make
```

**■動作**

このプログラムをロードして `tilt` アプリケーションを起動してください。
基板を傾けると次のように `Tilt detected` というログが表示されます。
基板の傾きを元に戻してからまた傾けると繰り返し検出を行います。

```
NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-7.22
nsh> tilt
Sensing start...
Tilt detected! (Rise) 3
Tilt detected! (Rise) 7
Tilt detected! (Rise) 12
```

以上、ご参考になれば幸いです。
今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム